# Double and single parent(tree) in data struct (c++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, tree

I'm trying to return even and odd nodes in the tree data structure, but they return incorrectly, what could be the reason?
height code;

```
int height(struct node* root) {
    int lheight, rheight = 0;
    if (root == NULL) return 0;
    lheight = height(root->left);
    rheight = height(root->right);
    return max(lheight, rheight) +1;
}
```

double in height;

```
int double(struct node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) return 0;
    if (height(root) % 2 == 0) return 1;
    return double(root->left) + double(root->right);
}
```

single in height;

```
int single(struct node* root) {
    system("cls");
    if (root == NULL) return 0;
    if (height(root) % 2 != 0) return 1;
    return single(root->left) + single(root->right);
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]. It is not possible that something is returned incorrectly in the code you posted, because it wont compile. Not only it is incomplete, but it is bogus code. You cannot name a function `double`

Comment: What does "return even and odd nodes" mean? All three functions you posted return integers, not nodes.